# In Solr, SynonymFilterFactory expansion with delimiters + WordDelimiterFilterFactory => weird resulting query

Tags: solr, lucene

Here's my query analyzer definition:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="companysyns.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
```

In "companysyns.txt", I have a few expansions for typical company words, like this:

```
inc, inc., incorporated
```

When I send a query like this:

```
test:"some company inc"
```

I see this unexpected result in solr debug:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">test:"some company inc"</str>
<str name="querystring">test:"some company inc"</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
MultiPhraseQuery(test:"some company inc (inc incorporated)")
</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">test:"some company inc (inc incorporated)"</str>
```

which does not match "Some Company, Inc.".  But if I remove the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, then for the same query, I see:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">test:"some company inc"</str>
<str name="querystring">test:"some company inc"</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
MultiPhraseQuery(test:"some company (inc inc. incorporated)")
</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">test:"some company (inc inc. incorporated)"</str>
```

which does match.

If I keep the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, but remove the "inc." entry (the one with a period) from synonyms, then it also works:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">test:"some company inc"</str>
<str name="querystring">test:"some company inc"</str>
<str name="parsedquery">
MultiPhraseQuery(test:"some company (inc incorporated)")
</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">test:"some company (inc incorporated)"</str>
```

Any idea why `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` is messing up the synonym-expanded query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The WordDelimiterFilterFactory removes the dot in inc. Change the order of the filters and it should work just fine:

```
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="companysyns.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  But any reason why WordDelimiterFilterFactory, in removing the dot, messed up the query so badly?

Comment: Could you explain how WordDelimiterFilterFactory created this: <str name="parsedquery_toString">test:"some company inc (inc incorporated)"</str>  I would've expected something more like test:"some company (inc inc incorporated)"